# Navigation Drawer not navigating

Tags: java, android

I have create a navigation drawer, i don't want to use fragments but instead activities. I have added this code which was working in many tutorials that i have watched.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {

        case R.id.Daily: {
            Intent h= new Intent(goals.this, Daily.class );
            startActivity(h);
            break;
        }
    }
    //close navigation drawer
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}
```

Whenever i click on the page i would like to navigate to. The drawer closes and nothing else happens. I am just a beginner so i don't know how to proceed. I have watched about 10 tutorials and this is what they say work but it doesn't and i am not sure why. The onNavigationItemSelected method has a grey line under it, saying that the method has no been used.

Resources:

My XML for the goals activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mitchell.tfit.goals">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#414E68"
    app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_profile"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu">


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_daily"
    tools:context="com.example.mitchell.tfit.Daily">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutSteps"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_panels"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblSteps"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Steps"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="112dp"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#6E8528"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.97"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:text="Current Goal:"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#6E8528"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.029"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutExercise"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_panels"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:text="Current Goal:"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#6E8528"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblExercise"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Weight"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutMeals"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_panels"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Weight Goal"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Step Goal"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblMeals" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblMeals"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Edit Goals"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_start"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_camera_nav"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/gallery_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/background_nav_button"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera_icon1" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java for the Daily activity

```
package com.example.mitchell.tfit;


import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class Daily extends AppCompatActivity {


private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily);




    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle =  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.Daily: {

            break;
        }
    }
    //close navigation drawer
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    return true;

}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return (true);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

XML for my drawermenu:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/Daily"
    android:title="Daily Tracker"
    android:icon = "@drawable/daily_icon"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/Goals"
    android:title="Goals"
    android:icon = "@drawable/goals_icon"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/Settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:icon = "@drawable/settings_icon" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/Logout"
    android:title="Logout"
    android:icon = "@drawable/logout_icon" />
```

Goals activity java:

```
package com.example.mitchell.tfit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class goals extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_goals);


    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle =  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();



    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}
```

Comment: What is Daily? Is that an activity?

Comment: @PrisonMike yes. Daily is an activity.

Answer (score 1):

Your Activity needs to implement `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` and you have to set the listener for your `NavigationDrawer`. Something like this should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // rest of code
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
The `NavigationViewer` in the XML of your `GoalsActivity` should look like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#414E68"
    app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_profile"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu">
```

Furthermore, add this to your `GoalsActivity.java`, inside the `onCreate()` method:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: This gives me this error :  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                      at com.example.mitchell.tfit.goals.onCreate(goals.java:29)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6864)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)

Comment: You are casting the wrong object. You need to pass the id of the `NavigationView` to the `findViewById()` method. Post your java and XML and I'll help you.